# IEEE case: 2 authors, 1+1 Affiliations

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

It is pretty clear in the IEEE format (for conference) that if less or equal than 3 authors are to be used, one should go with the block mode.

However, what happens if one of the two authors have 2 affiliations?  Should I go with this (1):

[image]

Or this (2)?

[image]

What is the official IEEE position regarding this situation?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Every IEEE article I know has the footnotes on the left column on the first page for the affiliations. Which transactions have this?

Comment: @percusse it's for a conference, you are talking about article templates

Comment: Sure but same holds for conferences too. Do you have any conference proceedings that adopts this? (Just curious usually it's the plain serif font in bold and large for title with names under it and footnote affiliations in my field)

Comment: @percusse sure, take a look [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6363331&searchWithin%3Dp_First_Names%3AMario%26searchWithin%3Dp_Last_Names%3AEspinoza%26matchBoolean%3Dtrue%26queryText%3D%28p_Authors%3AEspinoza%2C+Mario%29) :)

Comment: @percusse I can even give you the two different templates: for [journal articles](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html) and [conference proceedings](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html)

Comment: This is generally what I mean with ieee conferences; here is another paper from the same conference that uses ieeeconf instead of conference mode of ieeetran; http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SBR-LARS.2012.12 I also published regularly on RAS and CSS conferences and the general idea is to stick to `ieeeconf`. The reason is that the title takes up too much space. Hence most conferences stopped using that template.

Comment: @percusse Is ieeeconf a global option of the `IEEEtran` class?

Comment: No it's another cls file. You can find it online and on CTAN too but the there are too many modified versions lying around. I think IEEE stopped caring about the proceedings and accepts anytihng that looks barely ok.

Comment: @percusse If that is the case... then which one do you think I should choose? (1), (2) or ieeeconf?

Comment: Well based on purely space constraints (no beauty) I would go with `ieeconf` since it has only a small title and authors don't take up too much space.

Comment: @percusse and stetics whise?

Comment: then i would say none :P

Comment: @percusse We engineers are not known for our sense of beauty when it comes to writing :(