# IEEEauthorblockN

Tags: titles, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am trying to use the [ieeeconf template](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/tex.php#latexclass). When I am using the

```
\begin{document}
\author{It is me}
\maketitle
```

it typesets.

However, I want affiliations and change author to

```
\begin{document}
%\author{It is me}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Xin Liu, Daqiang Zhang, Jingyu Zhou, Minyi Guo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Computer Science\\
Shanghai Jiao Tong University\\
No. 800, Dongchuan Road, Shanghai, P.R.China\\
\{navyliu, zhangdq\}@sjtu.edu.cn, \{guo-my, zhou-jy\}@cs.sjtu.edu.cn}
}
\maketitle
```

(I have cut-paste of the names from some internet search result), I am getting

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@author -> \IEEEauthorblockN 
                              {Xin Liu, Daqiang Zhang, Jingyu Zhou, Minyi Gu...
l.36 \maketitle
```

Comment: See the comments of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138643/ieee-case-2-authors-11-affiliations . `ieeeconf` doesn't have a conference mode it is the IEEE (conf)erence template without the author blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get. What is the conference mode, conference template and author blocks? How do I add my affiliation in ieeeconf mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, we need to make ourselves clear about something.  There is `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` and there is `\documentclass[conference][{ieeeconf}`.  They both produce similar, but different things.

More specifically, `\documentclass[conference][{ieeeconf}` uses different author affiliations (they use numbers and then some kind of "footnote" for them on the first page), use CAPITAL letter (although they already are small-capped) for section titles and the `References` section has a smaller font size.

So, since it seems you are more than 3 authors, you should do something like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,conference]{ieeeconf}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts % Don't forget this command!

\begin{document}

\title{This is my title}}

\author{%
Xin Liu$^{1}$, Daqiang Zhang$^{2}$ and Jingyu Zhou$^{3}$% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$X. Liu is with the Faculty of Engineering, University of China
                    1234--465 Shangai, China
        {\tt\small xi.liu@china.cn}}%
\thanks{$^{2}$D. Zhang is with the Faculty of Engineering, University of China and Singapure Institute of Medicine
                    4275--465 Milano, Italy
        {\tt\small d.zhang@italia.it}}%
\thanks{$^{3}$J. Zhou is with the Faculty of Sport Sciences, University of Porto
                    4298--780 San Jose, Costa Rica  
        {\tt\small j.zhou@costarica.cr}}%
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
}
\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}
Hola

\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This hardcodes the numbers 1, 2, 3. That may conflict with footnotes, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have determined that IEEEauthorblockN works if I set `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` instead of `\documentclass[conference]{ieeeconf}`. But, I am not sure that this is a good solution since I have no idea what is the difference between `ieeeconf` and `IEEEtran`.