# \IEEEauthorblockN in ieee is not working

Tags: ieee-style, ieeeconf

I have read this post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139855/ieeeauthorblockn) and it seems there is some differences between the styles. I am using this template

`\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}`

and I want to add two authors. If I use `IEEEauthorblockN`, according to the aforementioned post, it won't work because the difference between the styles. The guy didn't provide a solution for adding two blocks. Now, how  can I add two blocks of authors in `ieeeconf` style?

Comment: ieee conferences don't have author blocks as article have. Use one author block for all authors. That's pretty common practice in many conferences.(computer society has different practice though)